# Angular creates multiple subscriptions when routing back and fourth

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, timer, ngrx

In my ngOnInit of my component I call a polling method. In my ngOnDestroy I unsubscribe to this method. 
Now, when I route back to the same component again and trigger my ngOnInit I now have 2 subscriptions. Whenever I leave the component I unsubscribe in my ngOnDestroy.
This pattern continues, increasing my subscriptions by one each time I visit the regarded component. How do I get rid of this behaviour?

Please let me know if I could provide more code or details to make things clearer. Thanks in advance!

See code below:

```
  // app.component.ts
   ngOnInit() {

   // init of my store, selecting the selector and subscribing to it 
this.store.select(fromStore.getAllVehicleDetails).subscribe(data => {
      this.updateVehicleStates(data);
      this.updateFavoriteVehicles();
      this.vehicleDetail = this.getVehicleDetail(this.selected);
    });

   this.store.select(fromStore.getFavVehiclesId).subscribe(data => {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         this.favVehicleIdMap.set(data[i].id, data[i]);
  }
});
   this.subscribeToData();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('dead');
    this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  /* Poll-function */
  private subscribeToData(): void {
    this.timerSubscription = Observable.timer(0, 10000).subscribe(() => {
      this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadVehicleDetails());
      this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadFavVehiclesId());
    });
  }
```

[image: dead]

Comment: Are you getting the 'dead' message in the console?

Comment: @samnupel yes I am! I'll update my post with a screenshot.

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't caused by the other subscriptions you have in your `ngOnInit`? You are not unsubscribing from those which is most likely the culprit

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel you were right! thanks man. I can't believe I missed that one. Problem solved. I'll post our solution in a second.

Comment: As a note, with this many subscriptions being done, it will be best to use the `takeUntil` operator way of unsubscribing https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/01/different-ways-unsubscribing-rxjs-observables-angular/

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Thanks for the advice!